# Возможно ли в Upsourse запускать unit тесты Android приложений?

Tags: android, jetbrains, непрерывная-интеграция

Есть всем известный jenkins, а возможно ли выполнять схожие действия по сборке и запуску тестов с помощью Upsourse?

Answer (score 2):

`Upsource` - это просто репозиторий, как `GitHub`, `GitLab` или другие, но от компании `Jetbrains`. То есть с помощью самого `Upsource` тесты не запустить.

`Jenkins` - `Open Source` система непрерывной интеграции (`Continuous Integration` "CI"). Её можно настроить для работы с любым репозиторием.
У `Jetbrains` есть своя `CI` - [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)